# Control whether Bison rule matches within action?

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

**tl;dr** Is it possible to use a Bison action to indicate whether the corresponding rule should match?

---

**Motivation:**

I am looking to write a Bison/Flex based parser for [the family of DIMACS graph formats](http://archive.dimacs.rutgers.edu/Challenges/), which are not standardized, and of which several variants exist. Thus I would like the parser to be forgiving.

The format generally looks like this:

```
c this is a comment
p format_type ...
a ...
b ...
c ...
```

I.e.,

- Each line starts with a single letter, the *line descriptor*, that indicates how the line should be interpreted.
- `c` lines are comments.
- The first non-comment line is a `p` line that defined the format variant. This determines what types of lines to expect next, and how to interpret them.
- Depending on the format type, different types of lines may follow. The same letter may indicate different kinds of lines in different format variants.

I would like to make the parser tolerant, and skip line types that it does not know about for the given format type. As a Bison/Flex novice I am not sure how to write a rule for skipping unknown lines.

**Example:**

Suppose we have two format types, `edge` and `max`. `edge` can have `e` lines and `max` can have `a` lines.

Example file 1:

```
p edge
e 1 2
a 2 3    <-- should be skipped
x 4      <-- should be skipped
```

Example file 2:

```
p max
e 1 2    <-- should be skipped
a 2 3
x 4      <-- should be skipped
```

In Bison, how can I write a rule for lines appearing in `edge`-format files, and allow skipping unknown lines? What is the best way to create tokens for line descriptor characters to allow this?

Suppose I have a single token for any line descriptor, e.g. in Flex,

```
^[a-z] { return DESCRIPTOR; }
```

How can I then write Bison rules that match not every kind of descriptor, but only `'e'`? Is it possible to restrict matches within the action?

```
edge_line: DESCRIPTOR integer integer { 
    match_only_if_DESCRIPTOR_is_e(); // POSSIBLE?
}
```

Suppose I have different tokens for each possible descriptor letter, something like this in Flex:

```
^[a-z] { return yytext[0]; }
```

Now I can write a Bison rule that matches `e`. But how can I write an alternative for "any other line descriptor"?

```
edge_line: 
    'e' integer integer { do_something(); }
  | [WHAT GOES HERE?]
```

Comment: I'd probably write code to report/reject (ignore) the unacceptable lines rather than trying to jigger the grammar.  Another option might be to modify the Flex tokenizer to use start states — but it would likely be better to read the unacceptable lines and process them, or not, according to the rules for the most recent 'p' line.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What would be the best approach to ignore the unacceptable lines? Sorry if I misunderstood your comment. Perhaps you mean that Bison is not the best tool for my use case?

Comment: I'd expect your grammar to accept a p-line followed by an arbitrary sequence of a-lines, e-lines, and x-lines.  You'd parse these lines as if they were valid but then simply reject the file, report the lines, or (least desirable from my point of view) ignore the lines that are not relevant for the most recent p-line, either as each a-line, e-line or x-line is processed, or when you finish one block of lines.  I assume c-lines don't cause any trouble.

Comment: Using a full-blown LR parser for such a grammar seems like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. I would write some simpler custom parser that just reads each line, splits it by white spaces, verifies if the first column is a single letter and then just uses a `switch` to decide what to do next. It would be much easier to control.

Comment: @PiotrSiupa That's a useful answer, thanks for the feedback. What I was looking to get from Bison was good error messages and easier extensibility (whenever we encounter a slightly different variant of this format in the wild). I expected that if the format is simple, it should be simple to handle it with Bison, but that may not actually be the case.